# Concatenate CString and Long in VC++?

Tags: c++, casting, atl, tostring, cstring

I have to concatenate two `CString` variables and two `long` variables in one
`CString`. I found one Format function that I have used like this:

```
CString str = "Some Data";

str.Format("%s%d", str, 123);
```

But it is giving errors. Here is the error log:

```
\AudWinSockXCtrl.cpp(410) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [10]' to 'ATL::CStringT'

        with

        [

            BaseType=wchar_t,

            StringTraits=StrTraitMFC

        ]

        Constructor for class 'ATL::CStringT' is declared 'explicit'

        with

        [

            BaseType=wchar_t,

            StringTraits=StrTraitMFC

        ]

.\AudWinSockXCtrl.cpp(411) : error C2664: 'void ATL::CStringT::Format(const wchar_t *,...)' :
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [5]' to 'const wchar_t *'
        with


        [

            BaseType=wchar_t,

            StringTraits=StrTraitMFC

        ]

        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or
function-style cast

.\AudWinSockXCtrl.cpp(414) : error C2664: 'void ATL::CStringT::Format(const wchar_t *,...)' :
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [4]' to 'const wchar_t *'

        with

        [

            BaseType=wchar_t,

            StringTraits=StrTraitMFC

        ]

        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or
function-style cast
```

Is there any function like `toString()` like we use in Java?

Answer (score 1):

```
CString str = _T("Some Data");
str.Format(_T("%s%d"), str, 123);
```

Read up on `_T` and `<tchar.h>` here: [Generic-Text Mappings in Tchar.h](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) .

Answer (score 0):

[sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf) ( OutputBuffer, "%s%d", str, 123 ) ;

1. Use CStringA for ANSI Version.
2. Use CStringW for Unicode Version.
3. Use CString for TCHAR Version.

To force CString to be evaluated as CStringA::
 Goto, Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->General.
 On right hand side, you will get "Character Set" Row, change that to "Not set"